# Render unicode subscripts

Tags: luatex, unicode

Does anybody have any ideas how to get the following to render properly?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
[Objective[|Ψ₀(2)⟩ to |Ψ₁(2)⟩ via [H₀[2,2], [H₁[2,2], u₁(t)]]]]
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

I'm compiling this with `lualatex`, but the unicode subscripts and the brackets are missing from the output. I'm open to any other tex engine, and using any font (I tried Code2000, which, aside from being very ugly, did not help).

This minimal example is from trying to compile the Sphinx documentatation of a Python project (https://krotov.readthedocs.io) to PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a monospaced font that has all the required characters.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
[Objective[|Ψ₀(2)⟩ to |Ψ₁(2)⟩ via [H₀[2,2], [H₁[2,2], u₁(t)]]]]
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Duh! Using the same font that I have in the terminal should have been pretty obvious! Thanks!